# Как начать написание тестов для java, а также spring?

Tags: spring, java, юнит-тесты

До текущего момента как-то игнорировал тему написания тестов для своих классов. Столкнувшись со спрингом, понял, что теперь без них не обойтись. Везде рекомендуют и т.д. Но так как я игнорировал эту тему, то знания по ней, конечно же, нулевые. Так вот:

1. Вроде как используются junit в тестировании, но я заметил ещё какой-то mockito. Это кто такой? Стоит ли нубу браться за мокито?
2. В спринге используются свои классы, похожие на те, что используются в пакетах самого junit. Это для чего? Для чего в спринге свои классы для тестирования?
3. И вообще, с чего начать эту тему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Вроде как используются junit в тестировании, но я заметил ещё какой-то mockito. Это кто такой?

Есть много фреймворков для тестирования, и jUnit / TestNG - просто самые известные. Mockito используется для создания моков - фальшивых копий объектов, которые позволяют таким образом обойти зависимости объекта от других объектов и протестировать непосредственно необходимый класс, а не класс-в-связке-с-другими-классами.

Answer (score 3):

Начните с чтения теории (хотя бы статей), смотрите на примеры. Для чего нужны те или иные классы читайте в javadoc-ах, благо у Spring-а они есть. Также в документации к Spring есть целый [раздел посвященный тестированию](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html), его тоже стоит прочесть.

Comment: @argamidon, эм, в общем-то сложно посоветовать другое. Тестирование очень простая штука - подтвердить, что данные на входе сгенерируют правильный вывод, проблема в том, чтобы это было действительно независимо и действительно покрывало возможные баги.